# Disconnect warning message in my master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I have to ask the user if he realy want to logout when he click on "logout".
My logout is on my navbar on my masterpage so I must do that with a link. Before I called an another page and on the page_load I put the session variable at Null then I redirect to the log Page.
But It's not realy good :

1- I can't call my javaScript function just with an onload

2- If the user cancel the disconnect I redirect him on a page but he loose the actual work if he didn't save

The JS code to ask :

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
     function Confirm() {
         var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
         confirm_value.type = "hidden";
         confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
         if (confirm("Êtes vous bien sûr de vouloir vous deconnecter ?")) {
             confirm_value.value = "Yes";
         } else {
             confirm_value.value = "No";
         }
         document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
     }
</script>
```

The best solution is a solution who permit to stay on the actual page, ask to the user with the js code ( or an other solution ) and if he say Yes, disconnect him.

Comment: How is this related to C#?

Comment: Because maybe a solution is to execute c# code but I don't know how

Comment: Perhaps executing some Cobol.Net will do. Why not add those to? Sorry, but you should have a very clear Idea, why you put in a tag

Comment: I never heard about cobol.net, have you got a great tutorial on this ? Because I just find presentation or forum on this when I search...

Comment: Sorry for the missleading comment of mine. That was just sarcastic. I meant to tell you that there is currently no need for the C# tag as no C# code is involved in your question. asp.net tag is absolutely sufficient here

Comment: Oh ok I understand your joke ;-) so ok I remove c# tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a very simply solution, I didn't know that was possible, but it's very usefull !

```
 <li><a href="../act_deconnexion.aspx" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" >Deconnexion</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `LoginStatus` Control in aspnet. You can add a confirm dialog there.

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" onclick="return confirm('Really logout?')"
    OnLoggedOut="LoginStatus1_LoggedOut"  />
```

It also works with a normal LinktButton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Really logout?')">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't use the asp authentification, when a user use the connection I just create a session variable then when the user disconnect I put this at null

Comment: You can do the same with a LinkButton. Then you can set the Session to null in the method in code behind.